# C++ Defining a (static) lambda function inside a class

Tags: c++, lambda

Here's the starting point for my question. Some code which does not compile.

```
class MyClass
{

    // for sorting
    auto lambda = [](const auto& x, const auto& y)
    {
        return x.x < y.x;
    };

    // something that needs a custom way to sort
    std::set<SomeOtherClass, lambda> mySet;

};
```

The error produce by the compiler is

```
error: non-static data member declared with placeholder ‘auto’
auto databaseSortLambda = +[](const auto& x, const auto &y)
```

It looks like a simple fix. Put `static` in there somewhere. My understanding is that this *won't* work, because this defines a static variable called `lambda` which has the type "closure object", rather than the lambda function itself being a static function.

```
class MyClass
{

    // for sorting
    static auto lambda = [](const auto& x, const auto& y)
    {
        return x.x < y.x;
    };

    // something that needs a custom way to sort
    std::set<SomeOtherClass, lambda> mySet;

};
```

This produces the following compiler error:

```
error: ‘constexpr’ needed for in-class initialization of static data member ‘MyClass::<lambda(const auto:1&, const auto:2&)> MyClass::lambda’ of non-integral type
```

The question is why? My understanding of `constexpr` is that it tells the compiler that it should calculate the result of an expression, and use that rather than calculating the expression at runtime.

In this case, how can this lambda be a `constexpr`? Surely the value of `x.x < y.x` cannot be known until runtime?

Is the compiler just telling me something meaningless at this point? And is there a way to write my lambda as a "static function" inside the class?

Comment: The value of `x.x < y.x` cannot be known until runtime, but _the lambda object itself_ doesn't need to know those values to be initialized. It just needs to be able to define its `operator()`.

Comment: `constexpt` means can be ran at compile time, not must be.  All `constexpt` functions can be called and ran at run time.

Comment: @user17732522 A static function cannot be passed as a template parameter to `std::set`

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant Oh sorry, I did not realize you want it to be generic. I should read more carefully.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant You can use a static member function as the comparator for a `std::set`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08a2acc022729af8

Comment: @NathanOliver Note OP want parameters as `auto`. In your given demo, you have use `int` as parameter types.

Comment: @JasonLiam Do they?  They want a comparator for a `std::set` so that is going to `SomeOtherClass` in the OPs example.  I figured the `auto` was used because it's shorter and more convenient.

Comment: @NathanOliver Looking at the earlier comments, it looks like OP is not using `auto` for making shorter code but instead for making  code more generic. Atleast that seems to be the intention.

Comment: Considering that I am specifying the type to `std::set` explicitly, there is actually no issue with not being able to use `auto` here. However, defining another `struct` just to put a static function inside, which can then be used as a function object, is what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: @JasonLiam What comment gives you that intention?  The only comment from the OP is they can't use a static function for a `std::set`.

Comment: @NathanOliver I am talking about [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73377176/c-defining-a-static-lambda-function-inside-a-class?noredirect=1#comment129584242_73377176) which was not by OP but OP didn't object to this so i assumed that `auto` was used for being more generic. Also, OP didn't mention that they used `auto` for making code shorter instead of making code more generic.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant You don't need to define another struct.  A function pointer is a perfectly good comparator type.  Example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aea30a07a6fc8864

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that can be meant when one says that the lambda is `constexpr`.

There may be a `constexpr` qualifier on the lambda *expression* itself. This determines whether the `operator()` of the closure type generated from the lambda expression is `constexpr`-qualified (although it will be `constexpr`-qualified even without that specifier if the `operator()` would satisfy the requirements for a function (template) to be `constexpr`-qualified).

The other is that the *variable* to which you store the lambda is `constexpr`-qualified. This has nothing to do with the the `operator()` of the closure type or equivalently its body. Instead it determines whether the lambda object itself is `const` and initialized by a constant expression.

A lambda that doesn't have any capture doesn't need to perform any action to be initialized. The lambda expression itself can be used in a constant expression (since C++17) and so there is nothing disqualifying the initializer from being a constant expression:

```
// for sorting
constexpr static auto lambda = [](const auto& x, const auto& y)
{
    return x.x < y.x;
};
```

Alternatively `inline` would also work.

Comment: `error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list`

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant You need to pass `decltype(lambda)`, not `lambda`. The latter belongs into the intializer of the set.

Comment: *you will need to still provide an out-of-class definition*, what does this mean I don't quite understand

Comment: Ah it seems out comments crossed

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant You can ignore that. I got things mixed up. (Assuming you are using C++17 or later which you must be to use a `constexpr` lambda in the first place)

Comment: I still don't think this will compile?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant What exactly?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant I forgot that all of this works only since C++17. Before that lambdas weren't allowed as constant expressions and therefore you probably can't make this work at all.

Comment: The compiler error is the one I posted as my first comment - when trying to use this as a (template) argument to `std::set`

Comment: I am using C++17, unless GCC isn't fully compliant on this particular aspect?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant `std::set<SomeOtherClass, decltype(lambda)> mySet;`. Or rather `std::set<SomeOtherClass, decltype(lambda)> mySet{lambda};` before C++20.

Comment: That also produces an error, but a different one. I should probably post a new question about it, but: `error: ‘ns1::ns2::MyClass’ has a field ‘ns1::ns2::MyClass::mySet’ whose type uses the anonymous namespace [-Werror=subobject-linkage]
`

Comment: ... and `std::set<SomeOtherClass, lambda> mySet{lambda};` produces the same error as the first !

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant That's just a warning (which you turned into an error with `-Werror`). There is no anonymous namespace in your question, so I can't tell why that appears here or how serious it is. I fixed the earlier comment.

Comment: Unfortunately all warnings are treated as errors, and that's not something I can change